# Having duplicate methods in association/composition relationship

Tags: class, oop, uml

Assume the class `Car` contains the class `Engine`. Now, `Engine` has some methods, namely `start()`,`stop()` etc. Now, I give the `Car` class to a `Driver`. I now want the `Driver` to `drive()` the `Car`. `Engine` already has a `start()` method. So should `Car` and `Driver` also have a `startCar()` method? I mean `Driver`'s `startCar()` method will internally call `Car`'s `startCar()` method, which will finally call `Engine`'s `start()` method. So is it a good practice to do so?

Other way to do so is I will do `Driver.getCar().getEngine().start()`. Which one is better in terms of code maintainability and OOP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/316678/law-of-demeter-and-its-applicability

It talks about [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and why you should usually avoid this type of chaining.